Pulling myself up with a pulley attached to myself
If I stand on a platform with a pulley attached. Can I pull myself upwards by pulling the end of the rope upwards?
My intuition tells me yes, but I cannot seem to find a way to draw a free body diagram where the forces are not balanced such that the elevator can lift me upwards. If I pull on the rope with a force F upward, the rope on the other side of the pulley must also have a tension of F. However, I am also experiencing the opposite reaction F downward from the rope, which I exert on the platform and the pulley downward. That means it cancels the force F exerted by the rope attached to the ceiling. How can I possibly produce an upward force to overcome the weight of the system and make the whole elevator accelerator upwards?
I think it must be possible since I can make a machine that rolls up the rope in constant speed. It is essentially just like pulling myself up a rope without a pulley. But I can't convince myself how the forces balance.


You're going to want to stand with one leg on either side of that pulley so that the platform doesn't rotate too.

Various other answers are correct and this FBD may help clarify. It's clear that a FBD of the whole system shows that the rope tension $T$ is equal to the combined weight $W$ of the person and the platform, neglecting upward acceleration.  I assumed the person to be massless and the platform to have all the combined weight, but it works out the same either way.
There may be a practical ergonomic advantage to this, but the mechanical force required would be the same as if there were no pulley.  But it certainly can be done.


It's better to link to the answer you refer to. "The previous answer" is harder to know

OK, clarified.  Sort of.

But this pulley has a diameter, so it seems that the balance of torque needs to be considered.

Balance of torque on which subset of bodies?  I was not considering the tipping of the platform, only the forces needed to raise it. Balance of torque on the pulley just tells you that the tension in the rope is equal on both strands (neglecting friction and inertia).  That result is independent of pulley diameter.


It is essentially just like pulling myself up a rope without a pulley.
But I can't convince myself how the forces balance.

You are absolutely correct. The only difference is the person will only have to lift his or her weight when directly climbing up the rope, whereas the weight of the platform will also need to be lifted. Moreover, as pointed out by @Mariano G it may be less advantageous to pull up on the rope than down as different muscles are involved.
It might be helpful to first analyze the forces involved in directly climbing up the rope. See FIG 1 below.
When the person pulls down on the rope, the rope exerts an equal and opposite force up on the person per Newton's third law due to static friction between the person's hands and the rope. However, there is a net force up on the person of $(T-mg)/m$ causing the person to accelerate up the rope per Newton's second law. Note that the upward reaction force of the rigid ceiling on the rope equals the downward force pulling force of the person on the rope, for a net force of zero on the rope so that there is no acceleration of the rope, per Newton's second law.
With the person on the platform as shown in FIG 2, the person is now pulling up on the rope and the rope pulling down on the person. Since a net upward force on the person is needed for the person to accelerate upward, the the platform needs to redirect twice the tension force upward on the person so that the net upward tension force on the person becomes the tension in the rope as in FIG 1 (Note I have shown the mass in FIG 2 as that of the person only as if the mass of the platform were negligible.  But one could  the combined mass of the person and platform. It is not important for the explanation.)
Hope this helps.



But this pulley has a diameter, so it seems that the balance of torque needs to be considered.

@enbin the pulley is considered frictionless

The tension of the rope on the left side of the pulley is not in line with the gravity acting on the person and the box, so a torque is generated, resulting in clockwise rotation.

@enbin In order for the pulley to rotate there needs to be friction between the pulley and the rope, which we are assuming is not present, otherwise we would not be able to assume the tension is the same throughout the rope. The fact is there is no need for a so called "pulley" in the first place. The circular object could just as well be a fixed, non rotatable, disc with a frictionless surface around which the rope is wrapped. Its only purpose is to allow one to pull up on the rope rather than down in order for the person to move up.

But the tension on the left side of the wheel and the gravity acting on the person form a moment (assuming the weight of the box and pulley is ignored), which also needs to be balanced.

@enbin If you move the person to the left so that his/her COG is directly over the middle of the wheel, would that satisfy you? Honestly, this is irrelevant with respect to the essential points being made here.

A more abstract reasoning also makes clear that it works: If you consider the platform plus wheel plus person a subsystem (for example, simply put it in an opaque box), its only connection to the outer world is gravity and the rope. All inner forces which complicate reasoning when we consider them (roll to floor, person to floor) are irrelevant. Yes, the person pulling up creates an equal and opposite force on the ground, but we don't care. They are part of the same system, and the force between the person and the platform is an inner force. The same goes for the wheel and the platform.
What the person's pulling does is increase the rope's tension which translates to an increased lifting force via the roll. That is an effect that crosses system boundaries and hence is observable from outside the system. The platform will move upward.

By the way, having the roll attached to the ceiling and pulling yourself up as in the image below is much better because you have another rope connecting your subsystem to the outer world, and you  are using them to the optimal benefit. The lighter the platform relative to the person, the better.


But this pulley has a diameter, so it seems that the balance of torque needs to be considered.

@enbin Yes, in reality you would devise a setup in which the torque is minimized or neutralized (by a guide). The sketch is a minimal rendering of the underlying idea.

This pulley provides no advantage and the person would do just as well to climb up the rope.  In the diagram provided, pulling the loose end of the rope upwards increases the upward forces on the rope each side of the pulley and when the combined tension is greater than the downward gravitational force the platform moves upward.


If I pull on the rope with a force F upward, the rope on the other side of the pulley must also have a tension of F. However, I am also experiencing the opposite reaction F downward from the rope, which I exert on the platform and the pulley downward. That means it cancels the force F exerted by the rope attached to the ceiling.

Yes, you exert a force $F$ downward, but this cancels the upward force from only one side of the rope. Each side of the rope is pulling up on the pulley and platform with the same force $F$, so the net upward force is $2F - F = F$.
